# application online security

Tags: vb.net, security

I am developing and application in vb.net winxp+ (windows xp upwards). The application has to receive backup data from clients software located at different pc over the Internet. but am concerned about security of this application on the Internet.

what would be the best way to implement security in vb.net 2008 to make sure that the data is not sniffed or interfere with?

am thinking of encrypting the data before sending, saving it that way until it need to be viewed before decrypting.

what type of encryption would you suggest?
Is there any other way you would suggest this data be sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your **Server Application has to be a Windows Service**. I imagine that your server will be always up, so a Windows Service is the right thing to implement.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you can find a reference on how to implement a Windows Service using .NET languages (it's very easy).

Then to secure the channel you have to do a choice about the type of encryption you want to use:

- **Symmetric**: AES, 3DES, BLOWFISH, etc.
  etc.
- **Asymmetric**: SSL or your home
  made protocol

The **symmetric** option ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/filesharingvb7.aspx) is an example) has an hard key management because you have to store all the client's keys onto the server. Or you can use the same key, but it's not secure because you have to protect very well the client key. If an attacker gets the client's key, whole security infrastructure is in the hands of the enemy.

But you can have a different symmetric key for every client and the server chooses the right one. Anyway you have to protect the client's code and key (obfuscation and so on)

The **asymmetric** option ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslclasses.aspx) is an example) is the best choice for me because you can have:

- client authentication to the server
  (the server has all the client's
  public key and verify the sign)
- server authentication to the client
  (the client have the server's public
  key)
- channel encryption (channel is
  encrypted with the symmetric session
  key handshaked by the clients and
  server through the public and private key)

The best and well-known protocol implementing the last one is SSL. You have to find APIs that implement it or you have to do by yourself (it's very hard to implement without bugs and security concerns).

Remember that you need certificate for SSL communications. X509 made via [**OpenSSL**](http://www.openssl.org/docs/HOWTO/certificates.txt) are good for your requirements and are easy to create.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different things you should consider here.

1. Is it a requirement that the backup data are encrypted on the server, in which case clients should encrypt data using a symmetric cipher (e.g. AES) before doing the transfer.
2. For the transfer itself, SSL (https) would be a solid solution, with server-only authentication.

Comment: thanks for responding. two questions. 1). Encrypting is a good idea, but with most knowledge about most encryption, AES might be easily decrypted. 2) i don't know how to do ssl with vb(vb6 or vb.net), especially ssl2 or ssl3. A sample code or tutorial might be of good help.